# Why Google Chrome resets its settings?

Tags: google-chrome

Sometimes Google Chrome resets its settings. My bookmarks are not deleted, but the bar and the homepage button are hidden and many of my settings (homepage, automatic translations, ...) are reset.

I have no installed extensions.

What could it be?

Comment: It probably happens after an update, but that's purely a guess

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this still happen to you?

Comment: If you are running Windows 10 then it is probably resetting many things after each of the major updates.

Comment: Thank you :) Maybe it was a bug, a wrong installation or an undefined conflict with some other software. I have never understood what caused this problem. Anyway, after a new installation of the software I have never seen this weird behavior anymore.

Comment: [Understand structure of Chrome User Profile data to Transfer to new PC](https://superuser.com/q/951095)
Google sucks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your user profile is corrupt. You should attempt to create a new one and see if this fixes the issue. **Here is how**

**For Windows**

- Exit Google Chrome completely.
- Enter the keyboard shortcut Windows key  +E to open Windows Explorer.
- In the Windows Explorer window that appears enter the following in the address bar.

  - Windows XP: %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\
  - Windows Vista/ Windows 7/ Windows 8: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\
- Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default."
- Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.
- If you wish, you can transfer information from your old user profile to your new one. However, this action is not recommended, since a part of your old profile may be corrupt. With that in mind, to transfer your old bookmarks, copy the "Bookmarks.bak" file from the "Backup default" folder to your new "Default" folder.
- Once moved, rename the file from "Bookmarks.bak" to "Bookmarks" to complete the migration. All other browser data will remain in the "Backup default" folder, but you won't be able to transfer it to your new profile.

**For Mac or Linux**

- Go here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059

Answer (score 1):

I think it keeps defaulting to "guest" mode despite you being signed back in. Maybe try disabling "allow guest browsing" when you sign back in to Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a home or work computer??
Some work places have policies to delete profiles and therefore no customization stay.
If you are at home make a backup and then uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: It is my computer (Dell Latitude E6500). I'll try what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Its wierd that you have this problem on your home computer. Nevertheless, try this if the system you are using is a un*x distro ( e.g. any linux distro) :

1. Open any terminal
2. Google chrome saves its configurations in `~/.config/google-chrome` directory. You can try to remove this directory to some safe place say your desktop and start afresh or you could try changing the permissions and ownership of the directory, by running the commands

   ```
   chown yourusername ~/.config/google-chrome -R  
   chmod u+rwx ~/.config/google-chrome -R
   ```

(On seeing any errors while running above commands use sudo and rerun that command.
If the system you are using is windows you can search the web for the location where google-chrome saves its configurations. It should be in local settings folder in your username's folder. Move that folder to some safe place say your desktop(in case something goes wrong later) Now start the chrome and customize it as you wish and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I created new profile for my chrome, but it didn't work and the problem didn't solve. But, I opened internet options and changed my homepage to www.google.com and voila, the problem solved. even after restarting the PC.

I think this problem happened to me because of the change in the homepage! and the point is I had never changed it. (my homepage automatically had been set at: wwww.startpage.com)

So, check your homepage. If yours is the same as mine, change it. It worked for me.