# Opera error “Can’t open user profile directory, because you lack sufficient privileges.” after Power Loss

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, administrator, opera, user-profiles

I am getting this message when I try to open Opera:

> Opera
>       Can't open user profile directory, because you lack sufficient privileges. You might want to contact the administrator of this machine.
>       OK

- I am the Admin on my PC and current User name is also on Admin group.
- Had **1st power failure** few days ago **while active on PC**, & after restart Opera worked fine.
- Then did the recent Opera security update and/ or update to latest Opera and this time **the PC was idle** and **opera had bunch of tabs open**, when the **2nd power failure happened**.

**Solution pathways: ??**

- Is there a within Opera fix for this? OR Does it have to be a Windows level fix?
- Would downloading a full Setup of latest Opera and installing on top (maybe as Admin) work to fix this issue?
- Should I do something like a "Take Ownership" on certain folders/ folder tree via Windows Explorer or similar?

Please let me know how to ENSURE I get access to this without losing my profile info. Thanks.

---

**Additional info:**

Since, this showed up I figured I should do a typical system check that I do using **[Image-Health](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/27180-windows-10-recovery-tools-bootable-rescue-disk-post434613.html#post434613)** which includes DISM & SFC command via an easy to run Menu system.

DISM ran fine, but SFC stopped at 23% and created at report (most of its lots of Hex/ Binary style info that doesnt share any file/ folder names of issue).

Now, for those saying SFC is not significant, let me repeat - All said checks, that I've used many times have worked fine before.

**So, I believe this Opera & SFC both facing permissions issues is kind of connected.**

The only other addition was installation of Windows 8.1 Security Rollup before these 2 power failures.

[SFC - System File Checker stuck at 23 24% - Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation](https://superuser.com/questions/1213694/sfc-system-file-checker-stuck-at-23-24-windows-resource-protection-could-no)

---

Permissions Screenshots combined: PS: At first this was concerning, but then the Read Only attrib is there on the AppData folders of all Applications, so I figure that may be the norm?

[image]

Comment: Provide the ACL for the folder in question.  Please provide all relevant tabs ina single screenshot of an appropriate size

Comment: @Ramhound - I suspect the folder in question is `"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software"` - I understand ACLs, but how would you like me to enumerate/ share them with you? I am taking screenshots for now - Is there a better ACL enumeration mechanism?

Comment: @Ramhound - Posted screenshots - Any thoughts/ responses?

Answer (score 1):

Opera Browser stores browser data in two folder in Windows::

- `"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Opera Software"` (only for cache)
- `"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software"` (for all browser/user data and preferences)

Backup bookmarks and you may delete/rename that folders (`rd /s /q` command) to solve your issue if you have not any valuable data in your Opera browser. Here are the path of that files to be backed up::

- Bookmarks:: `"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Bookmarks"`
- Preferences:: `"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Preferences"`

tl;dr; delete two folders and run Opera.

Download Opera offline installer:: https://get.geo.opera.com/pub/opera/desktop/

Comment: How are these 4 different? - https://get.geo.opera.com/pub/opera/desktop/45.0.2552.881/win/  - Also I'd like to ensure all my settings and extensions are not lost and usable as they were - https://superuser.com/questions/951095/understand-structure-of-chrome-user-profile-data-to-transfer-to-new-pc-os-avo

Comment: I cant afford to lose all the "data" inside the extensions - This was an issue in Chrome (linked), why I moved to Opera (also based on chromium( and now similar data loss in Opera.

Comment: Alright then try takeown and icacls command to set ACL recursively to all files and folders.

Comment: I am aware of that option, the issue is - I already have ownership - atleast from what I see in the ACLs - Also compared it to other Applications - Going to try with a different username to see how permissions are similar

Comment: Try to set all the owners and Grant permission to 'Everyone'

Comment: I just did a TakeOwnership (from being logged into existing Users\Username1) on the existing "Opera Stable" folder under AppData, using the Context Menu (already had it installed) thing from here: 

https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2814-take-ownership-add-context-menu-windows-8-a.html

Upon trying to open Opera I got the same message. 

PS: Also, logged into separate Users\Username2 and Opera opens up. So, it seems something inside existing profile is off. 

Do I need to create a fresh Profile folder and copy stuff into it or should a Take Ownership be enough?

Answer (score 1):

Opera browser uses the launcher.exe at `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera` in this folder you will see the latest updates version(76.0.4017.123) in a folder and the last used version(64.0.3417.73) also in a folder.

Now rightclick on the Opera browser shortcut on your desktop and select "properties".

Under the "shortcut tab" edit Target from `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\launcher.exe` to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\old version(64.0.3417.73)\Opera.exe`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and uninstalled Trend Micro Housecall and opera now works.
DRScanner.exe was holding the profile.