# SFC - System File Checker stuck at 23 24% - Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation

Tags: windows-8.1, sfc, system-file

Running SFC after 2 Power Failures on Desktop Windows 8.1 Pro.

Details here:
[Opera error “Can’t open user profile directory, because you lack sufficient privileges.” after Power Loss](https://superuser.com/questions/1213677/opera-error-can-t-open-user-profile-directory-because-you-lack-sufficient-priv)

**Additional info:**

Since, this showed up I figured I should do a typical system check that I do using **[Image-Health](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/27180-windows-10-recovery-tools-bootable-rescue-disk-post434613.html#post434613)** which includes DISM & SFC command options via an easy to run Menu system.

DISM ran fine, but SFC stopped at 23% and created at report (most of its lots of Hex/ Binary style info that doesnt share any file/ folder names of issue).

Now, for those saying SFC is not significant, let me repeat - All said checks, that I've used many times have worked fine before.

**So, I believe this Opera & SFC both facing permissions issues is kind of connected.**

The only other addition was installation of Windows 8.1 Security Rollup before these 2 power failures.

---

```
===============================================================================
  System File Checker is scanning the online image for corruption.
  Please Wait.. This will take 10-15 minutes or more..
===============================================================================

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 24% complete.

Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.
===============================================================================
  A SFC Details Report was Created on your Desktop
===============================================================================
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**SFC Details.txt**

```
2017-05-28 19:35:08, Info                  CSI    0000000a [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:08, Info                  CSI    0000000b [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:10, Info                  CSI    0000000c [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:10, Info                  CSI    0000000d [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:10, Info                  CSI    0000000e [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:12, Info                  CSI    0000000f [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:12, Info                  CSI    00000010 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:12, Info                  CSI    00000011 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:14, Info                  CSI    00000012 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:14, Info                  CSI    00000013 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:14, Info                  CSI    00000014 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:16, Info                  CSI    00000015 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:16, Info                  CSI    00000016 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:16, Info                  CSI    00000017 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:18, Info                  CSI    00000018 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:18, Info                  CSI    00000019 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:18, Info                  CSI    0000001a [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:20, Info                  CSI    0000001b [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:20, Info                  CSI    0000001c [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:20, Info                  CSI    0000001d [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:22, Info                  CSI    0000001e [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:22, Info                  CSI    0000001f [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:22, Info                  CSI    00000020 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:24, Info                  CSI    00000021 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:24, Info                  CSI    00000022 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:24, Info                  CSI    00000023 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:26, Info                  CSI    00000024 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:26, Info                  CSI    00000025 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:26, Info                  CSI    00000026 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:28, Info                  CSI    00000027 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:28, Info                  CSI    00000028 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:28, Info                  CSI    00000029 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:30, Info                  CSI    0000002a [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:30, Info                  CSI    0000002b [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:30, Info                  CSI    0000002c [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:31, Info                  CSI    0000002d [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:32, Info                  CSI    0000002e [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:32, Info                  CSI    0000002f [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:33, Info                  CSI    00000030 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:33, Info                  CSI    00000031 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:33, Info                  CSI    00000032 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:35, Info                  CSI    00000033 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:35, Info                  CSI    00000034 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:35, Info                  CSI    00000035 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:37, Info                  CSI    00000036 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:37, Info                  CSI    00000037 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:37, Info                  CSI    00000038 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:39, Info                  CSI    00000039 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:39, Info                  CSI    0000003a [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:39, Info                  CSI    0000003b [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:41, Info                  CSI    0000003c [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:41, Info                  CSI    0000003d [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:41, Info                  CSI    0000003e [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:42, Info                  CSI    0000003f [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:42, Info                  CSI    00000040 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:42, Info                  CSI    00000041 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:44, Info                  CSI    00000042 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:44, Info                  CSI    00000043 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:44, Info                  CSI    00000044 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:46, Info                  CSI    00000045 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:46, Info                  CSI    00000046 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:46, Info                  CSI    00000047 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:48, Info                  CSI    00000048 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:48, Info                  CSI    00000049 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:48, Info                  CSI    0000004a [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:50, Info                  CSI    0000004b [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:50, Info                  CSI    0000004c [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:50, Info                  CSI    0000004d [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:52, Info                  CSI    0000004e [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:52, Info                  CSI    0000004f [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:52, Info                  CSI    00000050 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:53, Info                  CSI    00000051 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:53, Info                  CSI    00000052 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:53, Info                  CSI    00000053 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:55, Info                  CSI    00000054 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:55, Info                  CSI    00000055 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:55, Info                  CSI    00000056 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:57, Info                  CSI    00000057 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:57, Info                  CSI    00000058 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:57, Info                  CSI    00000059 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:35:59, Info                  CSI    0000005a [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:35:59, Info                  CSI    0000005b [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:35:59, Info                  CSI    0000005c [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:01, Info                  CSI    0000005d [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:01, Info                  CSI    0000005e [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:01, Info                  CSI    0000005f [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:03, Info                  CSI    00000060 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:03, Info                  CSI    00000061 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:03, Info                  CSI    00000062 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:04, Info                  CSI    00000063 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:04, Info                  CSI    00000064 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:04, Info                  CSI    00000065 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:06, Info                  CSI    00000066 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:06, Info                  CSI    00000067 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:06, Info                  CSI    00000068 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:08, Info                  CSI    00000069 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:08, Info                  CSI    0000006a [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:08, Info                  CSI    0000006b [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:10, Info                  CSI    0000006c [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:10, Info                  CSI    0000006d [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:10, Info                  CSI    0000006e [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:12, Info                  CSI    0000006f [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:12, Info                  CSI    00000070 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:12, Info                  CSI    00000071 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:14, Info                  CSI    00000072 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:14, Info                  CSI    00000073 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:14, Info                  CSI    00000074 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:15, Info                  CSI    00000075 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:15, Info                  CSI    00000076 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:15, Info                  CSI    00000077 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:17, Info                  CSI    00000078 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:17, Info                  CSI    00000079 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:17, Info                  CSI    0000007a [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:20, Info                  CSI    0000007b [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:20, Info                  CSI    0000007c [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:20, Info                  CSI    0000007d [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:22, Info                  CSI    0000007f [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:22, Info                  CSI    00000080 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:22, Info                  CSI    00000081 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:25, Info                  CSI    0000009c [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:25, Info                  CSI    0000009d [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:25, Info                  CSI    0000009e [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:27, Info                  CSI    000000a7 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:27, Info                  CSI    000000a8 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:27, Info                  CSI    000000a9 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:30, Info                  CSI    000000b0 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:30, Info                  CSI    000000b1 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:30, Info                  CSI    000000b2 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:32, Info                  CSI    000000b4 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:32, Info                  CSI    000000b5 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:32, Info                  CSI    000000b6 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:35, Info                  CSI    000000bf [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:35, Info                  CSI    000000c0 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:35, Info                  CSI    000000c1 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:38, Info                  CSI    000000c4 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:38, Info                  CSI    000000c5 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:38, Info                  CSI    000000c6 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:40, Info                  CSI    000000c7 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:40, Info                  CSI    000000c8 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:40, Info                  CSI    000000c9 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:43, Info                  CSI    000000cb [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:43, Info                  CSI    000000cc [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:43, Info                  CSI    000000cd [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:47, Info                  CSI    000000e6 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:47, Info                  CSI    000000e7 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:47, Info                  CSI    000000e8 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:50, Info                  CSI    000000f8 [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:50, Info                  CSI    000000f9 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:50, Info                  CSI    000000fa [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2017-05-28 19:36:54, Info                  CSI    0000011e [SR] Verify complete
2017-05-28 19:36:54, Info                  CSI    0000011f [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2017-05-28 19:36:54, Info                  CSI    00000120 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
```

Comment: Why do you believe you need to run SFC?  Additionally, you should be running DISM not SFC since your using Windows 8+

Comment: Ran dism. Was fine. Ran sfc which never had issues before. Somethings got botched

Comment: See my prev but connected question about opera. Can't link via mobile

Comment: If DISM indicated nothing needed to repair then SFC failing isn't a real concern.  I am to lazy to read another question.  Please make this question clear

Comment: On mobile, will post more once chkdsk completes

Comment: make sure you run sfc from 64bit cmd.exe if you use 64bit Windows 8.1

Comment: @magicandre1981 - Yes, it is 64 bit CMD - As I said, I've run this many times before, but 1st time facing such an issue

Comment: @Ramhound - Updated & added more info on the other but CONNECTED question - https://superuser.com/questions/1213677/opera-error-can-t-open-user-profile-directory-because-you-lack-sufficient-priv